# Executing external command using exclamation mark in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, external

In order to execute an asynchronous external command I currently use following snippet:

```
command = strcat('start python "', obj.path, 'scriptname.py"');
system(command);
```

Unfortunately, the above command is not portable, since 'start' is a windows only command. Is there a way to start an external command asynchronously with user defined input?

Using

```
! python "obj.path" "scriptname" &
```

is not a viable option, since I can't use user defined input as the path. Is there a way to use the behavior of '!' without using an operating system dependent command?

Comment: Just a point: you can use `!` with user input. Use `eval`: `eval(['!python "' user_path_string '" "scriptname" $'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, why not use

```
system(['python "' obj.path filesep 'scriptname.py" &'])
```

?

Comment: thanks, wasn't aware that windows also supported the ampersand

Comment: @anopheles: Yup, although I think it's indeed not documented...so, it *might* disappear in future releases without warning. But oh well :)

Comment: @anopheles: It's documented for the `!` -- see `help punct`.